# Updating multiple rows with different values through foreach - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve multiple rows, loop with foreach, and update each of those rows with a specific value (based on switch)

I get the `Method save does not exist` error. Not sure what should be the syntax for this using Eloquent.

```
$appointmentreminders = Appointmentreminder::where('appointment_id', '=', $id)->get();

foreach ( $appointmentreminders as $appointmentreminder) 
{
           switch ($appointmentreminder->timeunit) {
               case "minute":
                   $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
                   $reminder->subMinutes($appointmentreminder->time);
                   break;

               case "hour":
                   $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
                   $reminder->subHours($appointmentreminder->time);
                   break;

               case "day":
                   $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
                   $reminder->subDays($appointmentreminder->time);
                   break;

               case "week":
                   $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
                   $reminder->subWeeks($appointmentreminder->time);
                   break;

               case "month":
                   $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
                   $reminder->subMonths($appointmentreminder->time);
                   break;
             }

             $appointmentreminders->reminder = $reminder;
             $appointmentreminders->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
$appointmentreminders = Appointmentreminder::where('appointment_id', '=', $id)->get();

foreach ( $appointmentreminders as $appointmentreminder) 
{
  $appointmentreminder = Appointmentreminder::find($appointmentreminder->id);
  switch ($appointmentreminder->timeunit) {
     case "minute":
         $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
         $reminder->subMinutes($appointmentreminder->time);
         break;

     case "hour":
         $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
         $reminder->subHours($appointmentreminder->time);
         break;

     case "day":
         $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
         $reminder->subDays($appointmentreminder->time);
         break;

     case "week":
         $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
         $reminder->subWeeks($appointmentreminder->time);
         break;

     case "month":
         $reminder = clone($appointment->appointment_start);
         $reminder->subMonths($appointmentreminder->time);
         break;
   }

   $appointmentreminder->reminder = $reminder;
   $appointmentreminder->save();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks @Komal